# How to change a card template?

Tags: xetex, cards

I have a slight problem with a little project I'm working on. I downloaded a template online (from where I'm not exactly sure, since it's been a few months) to make my own business cards. This template is simple: it creates new commands for name, email, phone, etc. and then puts them on the paper, but 8 times over. Thus, it produces 8 cards per sheet. However, I bought some cardstock from the store a few days ago, and didn't notice that the cardstock is cut to produce 10 cards per sheet. So, could anyone possibly look at my template and try to change the code so that it prints 10 cards to a sheet instead of 8? I honestly have no idea how it positions the elements... all I know is how to change the text. Thank you in advance!

[My code](http://pastebin.com/py4bR5GD)

Note: my cardstock is designed for 3.5"x2" cards, and it has a 3/4" border on the left/right sides and a 1/2" border on the top and bottom sides. There is no space between cards like in my template (that is, the paper is perforated so that cards are side by side).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).   I am guessing here, but the lines `\multiput(0,0)(0,56){4}{` and `\multiput(0,0)(95,0){2}{` seem to be something of a 4x2 grid. So you could try changing the first `4` to a `5` to hopefully get a 5x2.

Comment: Don't forget to [Vote early and often!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often) for answers/questions you find helpful, and also do see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Please always include all relevant code directly here in your question, not with an external hoster!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the beginning of the `picture` environment to something such as

```
\begin{picture}(200,240)(-7,28)% changed last digit to 28
  \multiput(0,0)(0,56){5}{% increased from 4 to 5
    \multiput(0,0)(95,0){2}{% no change here
```

looks good on the PDF, but might need tweaking based on your exact card stock.

On the mac I had to use `24` instead of `28` for some reason, to get this image shown below.

### Notes:

- You will most likely need to play with some of these parameters to get it to print precisely for the card stock that you have. The only way to do that is try print this out, and see how close it is with you actual card stock, and reiterate.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, BoldFont={BentonSansMedium.otf}]{BentonSansBook.otf}

\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{purple}{cmyk}{0.82,1.00,0.00,0.12}

\setlength{\textwidth}{8in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\textheight}{10in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}

%\newcommand{\clogo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.625]{./Logo.jpg}}
\newcommand{\cname}{\textbf{\textcolor{purple}{My Name}}}
\newcommand{\ctitle}{My Position}
\newcommand{\cemail}{myemail@email.com}
\newcommand{\cadra}{\textbf{Address 1}}
\newcommand{\cadrb}{Address 2}
\newcommand{\cadrc}{City, State, Zip}
\newcommand{\ccontact}{t. 123.456.7890\hspace{4.44 pt}www.website.com}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(200,240)(-7,28)% changed last digit to 28
  \multiput(0,0)(0,56){5}{% increased from 4 to 5
    \multiput(0,0)(95,0){2}{% no change here
      \begin{picture}(89,51)(0,0)
        \put(0,52){\line(0,1){3}}
        \put(-1,51){\line(-1,0){3}}
        \put(89,52){\line(0,1){3}}
        \put(90,51){\line(1,0){3}}
        %\put(3,48){\line(1,0){83}}
        \put(14.5,27.75){\scriptsize \cname}
        \put(14.5,24.5){\scriptsize \ctitle}
        \put(14.5,21.25){\scriptsize \cemail}
        \put(14.5,14.75){\scriptsize \cadra}
        \put(14.5,11.5){\scriptsize \cadrb}
        \put(14.5,8.25){\scriptsize \cadrc}
        \put(14.5,5){\scriptsize \ccontact}
        %\put(4.75,35){\clogo}
        %\put(3,3){\line(1,0){83}}
        \put(0,-1){\line(0,-1){3}}
        \put(-1,0){\line(-1,0){3}}
        \put(89,-1){\line(0,-1){3}}
        \put(90,0){\line(1,0){3}}
      \end{picture}}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got exactly the results I needed by using the values 5 and 28 (as well as playing with the margins a tiny bit). It looks great! Thanks again.

Comment: Very useful and generic, thanks. I had to select 'LuaLaTeX' in Texmaker to get this to work.